# Using month as column family in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to design a table for storing time series data in HBase. Since all data that are written in a month will be read "all at once" for analysis, I was wondering whether **using the month (as a string, like '201501') as column family** was a good choice.

My application is going to save data as they arrive with timestamps then, at the end of the month, all data related to that month is going to be analyzed with a hadoop job.

According to the specs, all data in a column family will be stored together. Is this a good practice in terms of (1) design and (2) performance ?

I'm not sure, since this is that kind of choice that is far away from the relational world.

Comment: While it's not a direct answer to your question, if you're storing time series data in hbase, take a look at [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In General, having many column families in HBase hurts performance. I think more than 2 or 3 column families is not recommended when using HBase. I would suggest browsing through this [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/number.of.cfs.html) for more details.

Also, the column family is part of the table schema when you create the table.

Example: `create 'hbase_table',{NAME=>'columnFamily',VERSIONS=>3}`

So if you want a new column family for every month, you're going to have to alter the table schema to add column families whenever required, which is not ideal.

According to me, a good solution here would be to have the date ([or reverse timestamp](http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html)) in your rowkey. 
Example: `XXX-YYY-20150106` or `XXX-YYY-9223370616269200807` (reverse timestamp)

Then, when you want to analyse data between 1 month, you can scan the table for the date range. 
Example: `scan 'hbase_table',{STARTROW=>'XXX-YYY-20150101', STOPROW=>'XXX-YYY-20150201'}`

Comment: That won't work very well if you have to scan different XXX & YYY values (would require a full table scan), which seems probable. In that case, you can go wide and create a monthly column family (M:) with a proper TTL (24 months?) and use months as columns (i.e M:201501), that way you can provide just the column you need to the scanner.

Comment: As long as you know part of the rowkey (in this case the date/timestamp), it will still be a partial table scan. 
Knowing your XXX will be the best case  scenario, knowing YYY is the 2nd best case, and knowing only date would be the worst case partial scan. 
However, if date is the most important query parameter for the table, you could always design your rowkey as `20150106-XXX-YYY`. I don't think having a column family for each month is a good idea.

Comment: Any other thing than a prefix will require a full table scan if you need to process all rows for a given month. Using the date as a prefix for your rowkeys would create region hotspots which should be avoided at all costs, also the job wouldn't be evenly distibuted among servers. Been using multi column families for historical data (48month TTL) in production for a few years with great write performance and pretty fast mapreduce jobs, it's a common practice in fact. For even better scan performance you can dual write to the same colum of another family with a more restrictive TTL (3months).

Comment: Regarding the hotspotting issue, you can always use hashing on the rowkey to prevent it.

Comment: Also I would think that primary reason for using HBase would be to get quick response times to queries from users/applications or APIs. 
In this case, having column families to separate data logically would definitely work better than having column families for each month. Analyzing historical data is mostly a batch processing job, and I think that maintaining quick response times for queries would be more important than designing your entire table focused towards historical data analysis

Comment: 4 families: Data, Yearly, Monthly & Daily, very similar to what Lars does at his Hush app sample: https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/hush/src/main/java/com/hbasebook/hush/table/ShortUrlTable.java

Comment: Thanks, this will help me better understand your point of view

Comment: You're welcome, wasn't my intention to turn this into a discussion :) Just keep in mind that hashing the rowkey would bring us back to having to do full table scans to analyze one given month, which could make jobs very slow. In the end it gets down to the classic short-fat vs tall-slim discussion, multiple approaches can be valid depending on access patterns.